# Input string was not in a correct format message error during update record vb.net and mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have MySQL Database and VB.Net project.
I have created a sub to execute any SQL statement and it's working well.

```
Public Sub Me_Sub_GetUpdate(ByVal SqlStr As String, ByVal xPar() As MySqlParameter)
    Try
        xCMD = New MySqlCommand(SqlStr, Conn)
        xCMD.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        If xPar IsNot Nothing Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To xPar.Length - 1
                xCMD.Parameters.Add(xPar(i))
            Next
        End If

        If Conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then Conn.Close()
        Conn.Open()
        xCMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Conn.Close()
        xCMD.Dispose()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

when I use the next subroutine to update a record:

```
Try
         Dim SqlStr As String
         Dim xParam As MySqlParameter() = New MySqlParameter(1) {}
         xParam(0) = New MySqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.TinyInt)
         xParam(0).Value = 1
         xParam(1) = New MySqlParameter("@TheName1", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
         xParam(1).Value = Trim(Me.t1.Text)

         SqlStr = "UPDATE tblcominfo Set TheName1=@TheName1 Where ID = @ID"

         xCLS.Me_Sub_GetUpdate(SqlStr, xParam)
     Catch ex As Exception
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
     End Try
```

I got a message (Input string was not in a correct format)!!

When I deleted the parameters and run the update code with direct values it's working!!

I don't know what's the problem, can you help me?

Comment: Can you try to narrow it down to just one parameter that produces the error? Throw a little science at it.

Comment: I kept one parameter and the same message!

Comment: And if you switch to the other parameter? Does it work then, or do you get the same error?

Comment: Dim SqlStr As String
            SqlStr = "UPDATE tblcominfo Set TheName1 = '" & Trim(Me.t1.Text) & "' Where ID = @ID"

            Dim xParam As MySqlParameter() = New MySqlParameter(0) {}
            xParam(0) = New MySqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.TinyInt)
            xParam(0).Value = 1


            xCLS.Me_Sub_GetUpdate(SqlStr, xParam)

Comment: it's working with previous code so the problem with the second parameter, but what its problem?

Comment: Just to be clear, it works when you specify only `@ID` and it fails when you specify only `@TheName1` ?

Comment: yes, you're correct

Comment: You're not setting the `Size` property on the `@TheName1` parameter. That message doesn't seem right for a truncation issue but you never know...  Try assigning the length of the `TheName` column to `xParam(1).Size`.

Comment: xParam(1) = New MySqlParameter("@TheName1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50)

Comment: the same message

Comment: I think I got it... `SqlDbType.NVarChar` is not `MySqlDbType.VarChar`. It's calling the constructor overload for `(name As String, value As Object)`, so the default type is being used, whatever that is, probably `MySqlDbType.Decimal`.

Comment: OMG, yes, it's working now, you're great man, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `SqlDbType`, not `MySqlDbType`.  `SqlDbType` is used by the SQL Server provider.  Since you're using MySQL, you need to use `MySqlDbType`.

The constructor you're calling is not the one you expected:

```
new MySqlParameter("@TheName1", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
```

...is calling the constructor that takes `(name As String, value As Object)` because there's no overload that takes `SqlDbType`. You're then overwriting the value, and the `MySqlDbType` property is whatever the default is (probably `MySqlDbType.Decimal`).

On the other hand, if you pass a `MySqlDbType` value:

```
new MySqlParameter("@TheName1", MySqlDbType.VarChar)
```

...it will call the constructor that takes `(name As String, dbType As MySqlDbType)` and the `MySqlDbType` property will be initialized from it.

Comment: thank you so much dear, I have another question I'm using tinyint(1) datatype in mysql for ID what is the data type should use in parameter?

Comment: If I had to guess (and I can't do better than a guess on this), I would say `MySqlDbType.Byte`. `MySqlDbType.UByte` would be a close second.

Comment: yeah, that's what I did, thank you so much and I wish you all the best.